# Insert 6 images randomly in array[6][6]

Tags: android, random

//I made array for the images , and nested loop to repeat them 6 times , when i run the emulator generate "hello world" , how i can view them in the emulator ?

```
package com.example.abc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Integer []arr = new Integer [] {R.drawable.candy1, R.drawable.candy2, R.drawable.candy3,                        
        R.drawable.candy4,R.drawable.candy5 ,R.drawable.candy6}; 
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shuffleArray();
}
    private void shuffleArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Integer> pictures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            for (int j=0 ; j<6 ; j++)
            {
                 pictures.add(arr[j]);
                 Collections.shuffle(pictures);
            }

        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Topic line is totally misinforming!

Comment: I only see an `array[6]`, not an `array[6][6]`, here. And it fills a list with 36 items.

Comment: i don't know how to pass the 6 images in 2d array , so i made arr[6] and repeat it 6 times

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
private void shuffleArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Integer> pictures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            for (int j=0 ; j<6 ; j++)
            {
                 pictures.add(arr[j]);
                 Collections.shuffle(pictures);
            }

        }

    }
```

try this:

```
private void shuffleArray() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Integer> pictures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

             pictures.add(arr[j]);
             Collections.shuffle(pictures);

    }

}
```